# How can I get my code to read the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I've been trying to write a code that randomises a character for a game I play, however it was to large so I decided to save a few lines, but I can't get the part I'm working on to work

I've not tried much as I'm pretty new to coding, but I've looked online and non of the solutions worked
This is my code

```
import random as Shadow
def StatGen():
    import random as Shadow
    d1= (Shadow.randint(2,6))
    d2 = (Shadow.randint(2,6))
    d3 = (Shadow.randint(2,6))
    d4 = (Shadow.randint(2,6))
    stat1 = (d2+d3+d4)
    stat2 = (d1+d3+d4)
    stat3 = (d1+d2+d4)
    stat4 = (d1+d2+d3)
StatGen()
if (d1 < d2) and (d1 < d3) and (d1 < d4):
    print ("Your first stat is", stat1)
elif (d2 < d1) and (d2 < d3) and (d2 < d4):
    print ("Your first stat is", stat2)
elif (d3 < d1) and (d3 < d2) and (d3 < d4):
    print ("Your first stat is", stat3)
else:
    print ("Your first stat is", stat4)
  
StatGen()
if (d1 < d2) and (d1 < d3) and (d1 < d4):
    print ("Your second stat is", stat1)
elif (d2 < d1) and (d2 < d3) and (d2 < d4):
    print ("Your second stat is", stat2)
elif (d3 < d1) and (d3 < d2) and (d3 < d4):
    print ("Your second stat is", stat3)
else:
    print ("Your second stat is", stat4)
```

Comment: You are mixing up local (defined within a function) and global names. So `d1` etc  is assigned inside the function but this name is not known outside the function when you try to use if.  Also there is no point in importing Random a second time within the function - just delete this line.

Comment: Look into how to return values from a function.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because the variables `d1` to `d4` and `stat1` to `stat4` are only in scope in the `StatGen()` function.

You cannot access them outside of the function, unless you return those values from the function.

If I understand the intent of your code, it seems you are trying to generate 4 random integers within the range `(2, 6)` inclusive, and return their sum, excluding the smallest.

You can try this code:

```
import random


def stat_gen():
    """ Generates 4 random integers in the range (2, 6) inclusive,
    and returns their sum, excluding the smallest integer.
    """

    random_integers = [random.randint(2, 6) for _ in range(4)]

    smallest = min(random_integers)

    print(f"Random integers generated: {random_integers}")

    random_integers.remove(smallest)

    return sum(random_integers)


stat1 = stat_gen()
print("Your first stat is:", stat1)

"""
Example run:

➜  python python stat_gen.py
Random integers generated: [4, 2, 2, 6]
Your first stat is: 12

"""
```

I will leave it as an exercise for you to further extend the function so that it can generate any number of integers, and within an arbitrary range.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user19077881 you are right, I have edited my answer accordingly. 

BTW, `random.randint(a, b)` returns a random integer between a and b inclusive.

From the docs:

`random.randint(a, b): Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1).`